# How to create an SOCKS5 proxy with SSH that only uses IP and PORT

Tags: networking, ssh, vmware, proxy, socks5

I have Ubuntu 13.04 32-bit running in my Virtual Machine in VMware Workstation 9, I'm trying to make an SOCKS5 proxy with SSH which can be accessed from the host only using IP and PORT number, I know it is possible, but I don't have the know-how.

For the reason why? I want to have fine control over which applications I give internet access on my Windows Operating System, just because I do not trust Windows... at all.

Thanks in advance,
I'm open to solutions to my problem.

Comment: Is Windows the host OS, or the guest OS?

Answer (score 1):

You'd want to do

```
ssh -D 8080 localhost
```

This will bring up a SOCKS5 proxy on port 8080.

Comment: Yes, but that does not "remove" the needed authentication.

Comment: "remove" the needed authentication? There is no authentication on the proxy. Any application can connect to port 8080 and be proxied.